# closing jdbc connections in JTA

Tags: java, jdbc, jta, xa

What will happen when DbConnection.close() is called for a XA Reource?  Will it be returned to the connection pool or will it be held by the transaction manager until the Global Transaction finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been cracking my head and looking for so many place for the answer, but none can give me a confirmation.

Most of time, the actual Transaction Manager behavior is vendor-dependent. But you can refer to the JTA 1.1 Specification too for the standard behavior.

> 1. Assuming a client invokes an EJB bean with a TX_REQUIRED transaction attribute and the client is not associated with a global
>      transaction, the EJB container starts a global transaction by invoking
>      the TransactionManager.begin method.
> 2. After the the transaction starts, the container invokes the bean method. As part of the business logic, the bean requests for a
>      connection-based resource using the API provided by the resource
>      adapter of interest.
> 3. The application server obtains a resource from the resource adapter via some ResourceFactory.getTransactionalResource method.
> 4. The resource adapter creates the TransactionalResource object and the associated XAResource and Connection objects.
> 5. The application server invokes the getXAResource method.
> 6. The application server enlists the resource to the transaction manager.
> 7. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.start to associate the current transaction to the resource.
> 8. The application server invokes the getConnection method.
> 9. The application server returns the Connection object reference to the application.
> 10. The application performs one or more operations on the connection.
> 11. The application closes the connection.
> 12. The application server delist the resource when notified by the resource adapter about the connection close.
> 13. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.end to disassociate the transaction from the XAResource.
> 14. The application server asks the transaction manager to commit the transaction.
> 15. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.prepare to inform the resource manager to prepare the transaction work for commit.
> 16. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.commit to commit the transaction.

[image]

So to answer you question, while you call the `close()`, the connection will be delisted, it is somehow still being hold by the Transaction Manager, so you can safely call `close()` before commit to pre-return the connection to the pool (if you worry about connection leak), although there are lot of Transaction Manager will help to auto-close the connection without you to manually close it (refer to Hibernate framework and Transaction Manager).